# In django if i want to display files which i've uploaded them to a model how can i display each one alone?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm tryin to create a website the website should have some pdf files i've made a tmplate that contains all the files titles and used { for in } to display the titles  but i want to redirect them to a page that shows the pdf file when they click on the title how can i do that ? and thnx.

Comment: Where are you uploading the file?

Comment: I created a model named cart in this model i made a filefiled named cartes thrn i went to the admin section and uploaded some files in cartes help pls

Answer (score 0):

First you need to upload those pdf files on your server.

After that store the links of those pdfs in a list and pass it to html, now make the name of pdf hyperlink link this

> `<a href={{link of this particular pdf}}> PDF_NAME </a>`

Comment: Do i have to make a link to each pdf ? Can it be done automaticly ?

Comment: So if the files are on the same server, then just pass the relative path of the file.